# Add labels programmatically in a column

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

So here's my code. It doesn't work. The Labels do not appear. I've been unable to find my mistake.

```
 For i = 0 To 408 Step 51
        Dim text As Integer = 0
        Dim label as New Label
        Dim name As String = "lbl" + CStr(i)

        With label
            .Location = New Point(49, 33 + i)
            .Size = New Size(32, 32)
            .Name = name
            .Font = New Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", FontStyle.Bold)
            .Text = CStr(text)
            .Visible = True
        End With

        Me.Controls.Add(label)
        text += 1
    Next
```

Can someone point it out?

Comment: Wouldn't a [**`FlowLayoutPanel`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/walkthrough-arranging-controls-on-windows-forms-using-a-flowlayoutpanel) be better for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the line where you create the font to

```
.Font = New Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 12, FontStyle.Bold)
```

Specify the size otherwise it is defaulting to size 1. Not very visible.
Notice also that you set the *text* variable to zero at each loop, so all your controls have the same text.